# Even static object are movable in Translation mode

Tags: gazebo-2.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using [Translation Mode](http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_world&cat=build_world) I can move any objects on Gazebo AFA I tried, whether an object is `is_static` true or not. If this is true, is there a way to make objects not transferable?

Example

```
$ gazebo /usr/share/gazebo-2.2/worlds/willowgarage.world  
:
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 2.2.5
```

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9167/even-static-object-are-movable-in-translation-mode/) by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2015-08-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The `is_static` tag means something is not movable by physics, but it is still movable by the user.

You could try adding a joint from the world to the model. The user can drag it away but as soon as the mouse is released, the model should snap back to the original pose.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0